# Linux Permission the different between delete and create a file

Tags: linux, permissions

```
    dr‐x‐‐‐‐‐x. 3 joey joey 4096 Oct 12 2014 .
    drwxr‐xr‐x. 4 root root 4096 Oct 12 2014 ..
    ‐rw‐r‐‐r‐‐. 1 joey joey   18 May 22 2012 .bash_logout
    ‐rw‐r‐‐r‐‐. 1 joey joey  176 May 22 2012 .bashrc
    ‐‐w‐rw‐r‐‐. 1 joey ta    111 Feb 16 2014 ourGoal
    drwxrwx‐‐‐. 3 joey joey 4096 Nov 24 2014 project
    ‐rw‐r‐‐rw‐. 1 joey ta    492 Mar 11 2015 reportx
```

peter is the member of wm group and John is the member of ta.

1. if the guy(peter,joey,john) wants to read the file(reportx),the minimal permission is it .with x and file with r? or i don't need the x permission of .
2. if (peter,joey,john) want to create a file and edit the file(ourGoal), is it i need .with x and (ourGoal) with w?
3. if (peter,joey,john) want to delete the file(reportx), is it i need . whit x and . with w?

This 3 parts i can't really understand, and thx for helping.

Comment: Who is "the guy"??!!

Comment: peter,joey,john

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating and deleting files is based on **directory** permissions. Since only Joey has access to the directory no one else can create or delete files in that folder.

To read the file you need to have `r` access to it. To write to the file you need to have `w` access to it. In your case, anyone can read `reportx` and everyone in the group `ta` can modify it. Also, anyone can write to `ourGoal` but only members of ta or joey can read it.

Comment: Also, since only joey has `r` access to the current directory, only joey can see the directory listing of `.`. The others can access the files as you described, but only if they know the exact name of the file. When directory listing is denied, TAB completion won't work either.

Comment: To add, the user will need execute permissions to parent directory also in order to delete.

Comment: THX FOR HELPING